# How to connect Google earth with my website?

Tags: google-maps, web, maps, polygon, google-eclipse-plugin

I want to connect my website to Google Earth and allow the user to choose his location. After that allow the user to draw a polygon around his house or desired location.

Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine) API?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Earth Engine API was deprecated a few years back, but unless you're specifically looking for the globe, and other effects, you might do just as well with the Google Maps API.